# downloading r-studio, the git command line requires command line developer tools

Tags: r, git, command-line, rstudio

I have just downloaded R studio to a new computer, and i get a message saying ' the git command line requires command line developer tools, would you like to install'? I use R for educational purposes but don't know too much about things like software. Do I need this? When I press install it says expected 213 hours to download so I have pressed stop as I don't know what I'm actually downloading. Sorry for sounding so ignorant but need some help!!!

Comment: Do you plan to use `git` for version control of your source files? If not, then no need to worry about it. You can always install it later. I assume you are on a Mac?

Comment: yes on a mac. thank you so much!!!!